# Is there a certification available to become a saleforce.com's consultant ?

Tags: administration, certification, developer

I have found Developer's & Administrators certification details. But i did not find any certification to become a consultant. So is there any certification from salesforce.com available ? if so please let me know the details of it.

Comment: Did you try a search engine ?

Comment: Closing because this shows no research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sales cloud Consultant and Service cloud consultant certifications are available salesforce consultants certification , and the prerequisite  is ADM 201, please check below for more details

http://certification.salesforce.com/implementation-experts

And one good thing , u need not write maintain these certifications separately, only Admin maintainace is enough.